# Cannot list contents of directory with 0755 and owned by current user

Tags: usb, android, selinux

The platform is a rooted Android 8.1 phone ([Magisk](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk)) with the [Termux](https://termux.com/) *Android terminal emulator and Linux environment app* installed. I use this as a server on the go.

After connecting a USB smart card reader, then as root I can see its USB device files just fine. However as an ordinary user I cannot see these files, even after making the user owner of the containing directory:

```
$ whoami
u0_a88
$ ls -l /sys/bus/usb/devices
ls: cannot open directory '/sys/bus/usb/devices': Permission denied
$ ls -ld /sys/bus/usb/devices
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Aug 20 08:48 /sys/bus/usb/devices
$ su
# whoami
root
# ls -l /sys/bus/usb/devices/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 20 08:49 1-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/soc/a800000.ssusb/a800000.dwc3/xhci-hcd.0.auto/usb1/1-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 20 08:49 1-1 -> ../../../devices/soc/a800000.ssusb/a800000.dwc3/xhci-hcd.0.auto/usb1/1-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 20 08:49 1-1:1.0 -> ../../../devices/soc/a800000.ssusb/a800000.dwc3/xhci-hcd.0.auto/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 20 08:49 2-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/soc/a800000.ssusb/a800000.dwc3/xhci-hcd.0.auto/usb2/2-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 20 08:49 usb1 -> ../../../devices/soc/a800000.ssusb/a800000.dwc3/xhci-hcd.0.auto/usb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 20 08:49 usb2 -> ../../../devices/soc/a800000.ssusb/a800000.dwc3/xhci-hcd.0.auto/usb2
# chown u0_a88.u0_a88 /sys/bus/usb/devices
# exit
$ ls -ld /sys/bus/usb/devices
drwxr-xr-x 2 u0_a88 u0_a88 0 Aug 20 08:54 /sys/bus/usb/devices
~$ ls -l /sys/bus/usb/devices
ls: cannot open directory '/sys/bus/usb/devices': Permission denied
```

*What is happening here?*

Comment: Possibly the permissions on a higher level directory apply more strict acecss controls, a quick check on a long path is with the `namei` command: `namei -l /sys/bus/usb/devices`

Comment: @HBruijn, If it was about regular directory permissions higher on the path, `ls -ld /sys/bus/usb/devices` wouldn't work either. I do wonder if this is some Android thing.

Answer (score 2):

As I found out, it likely has to do with [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux):

```
$ su
# getenforce
Enforcing
```

Regular files can be given permission for access by the ordinary user as in the following example:

```
$ su
# echo foo >bar
# exit
$ cat foo
cat: bar: Permission denied
$ su
# ls -Z bar
u:object_r:app_data_file:s0 bar
# restorecon bar
SELinux: Loaded file_contexts
# ls -Z bar
u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 bar
# chown u0_a88.u0_a88 bar
# exit
$ cat bar
foo
```

Simply using `restorecon` and `chmod` is not sufficient, however, to give me
access to `/sys/bus/usb/devices`:

```
# restorecon /sys/bus/usb/devices
# chown u0_a88.u0_a88 /sys/bus/usb/devices
# ls -Zd /sys/bus/usb/devices
u:object_r:sysfs:s0
# exit
$ ls -ld /sys/bus/usb/devices
drwxr-xr-x 2 u0_a88 u0_a88 0 Aug 23 11:49 /sys/bus/usb/devices
$ ls -l /sys/bus/usb/devices
ls: cannot open directory '/sys/bus/usb/devices': Permission denied
```

I didn't try changing permissions higher up the path as I’m worried about
breaking the system.

(I assume that my explanation is right. Still an answer by someone knowledgeable
about SELinux would be nice.)

Comment: Try `ls -Zd /sys` and change it temporarily if you don't want to interfere with your system security.

Answer (score -1):

Everything inside the

> /sys/bus/usb/devices/

Is containing a softlink. The softlink default permission is always 777.

But the real file located inside

> /devices/soc/a800000.ssusb/a800000.dwc3/xhci-hcd.0.auto/

is the real file. 
You need to change the permission to 777  in the real location first to enable the user u0_a88 to open the directory/files.

Comment: The directory itself is not a symlink. So with permissions 0755, I should be able to see its contents, as any user. *Not?*

Comment: Other need execute permission to open the directory.